# iwlwifi throws error when it is loaded - Microcode SW error

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

My laptop has the Killer WiFi 6E AX1675 WLAN. I have iwlwifi installed, but it throws an error when it's loaded.

This is the error log -

```
[  850.276502] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-69.ucode failed with error -2
[  850.276509] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-68.ucode failed with error -2
[  850.276744] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[  850.276754] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.34
[  850.276950] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: loaded firmware version 67.8f59b80b.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[  850.301255] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Detected Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1675x 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (210NGW), REV=0x420
[  850.301293] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[  850.308217] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 1, ret=-1
[  850.308219] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 2, ret=-1
[  850.308219] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 3, ret=-1
[  850.453985] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: loaded PNVM version 324cd670
[  850.465788] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[  850.467281] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[  850.467398] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  850.467399] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[  850.467400] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 67.8f59b80b.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode
[  850.467401] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[  850.467402] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x002002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[  850.467403] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  850.467404] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004DAC6A | branchlink2
[  850.467404] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D108E | interruptlink1
[  850.467405] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D108E | interruptlink2
[  850.467406] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D9A0A | data1
[  850.467407] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000010 | data2
[  850.467408] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[  850.467408] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[  850.467409] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x0001462F | tsf low
[  850.467410] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  850.467411] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  850.467411] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000265AF | time gp2
[  850.467412] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  850.467413] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000043 | uCode version major
[  850.467413] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8F59B80B | uCode version minor
[  850.467414] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000420 | hw version
[  850.467415] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x18C89002 | board version
[  850.467416] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8008FF05 | hcmd
[  850.467416] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[  850.467417] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x60000000 | isr1
[  850.467418] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[  850.467418] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[  850.467419] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  850.467420] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[  850.467420] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x004D9A0A | wait_event
[  850.467421] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[  850.467422] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[  850.467423] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[  850.467423] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[  850.467424] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  850.467425] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  850.467425] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
[  850.467486] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  850.467487] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[  850.467488] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x2010070E | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[  850.467489] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[  850.467490] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8045E20E | umac branchlink2
[  850.467490] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x0109112A | umac interruptlink1
[  850.467491] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[  850.467492] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00001281 | umac data1
[  850.467493] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00001285 | umac data2
[  850.467493] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[  850.467494] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000043 | umac major
[  850.467495] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x8F59B80B | umac minor
[  850.467495] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000265A6 | frame pointer
[  850.467496] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0xC0885E88 | stack pointer
[  850.467497] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[  850.467498] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[  850.467534] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[  850.467535] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[  850.467545] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x000075CB | IML/ROM data1
[  850.467555] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[  850.467562] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  850.467565] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  850.467569] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x80440003 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  850.467572] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  850.467575] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  850.467579] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  850.467582] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  850.467585] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  850.467592] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  850.467595] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  850.467601] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  850.467606] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  850.467613] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  850.467687] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[  851.345390] iwlwifi 0000:30:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

When I installed it I used https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324314/no-wifi-adapter-found-with-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-install-on-msi-ge66-laptop-and-ot

It worked on my other Ubuntu installation on a bootable drive.

Do I need to reinstall iwlwifi, if so, how do I do it right?